# blog posting schema any suggestion?

Tags: blogs, schema.org, posting

is it ok for blogposting schema.org... Do you think there are errors?... any suggestions... thanks

```
<div id="blog_post" itemscope="" itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
<div style="float: left;">
<a href="image link is here">
<img itemprop="image" src="image source link is here" width="150px" alt="image description is here"/></a></div>
<div style="font-size: 10pt; font-weight: bold; margin-bottom: 10px;" itemprop="name">
<a href="item link is here" itemprop="url">item title is here</a></div>
<div id="description" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;margin-bottom: 10px;">
<span style="font-size: 11pt; font-weight: bold;" itemprop="description">item description is here</span></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing anything not related to Microdata, you have:

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">
  <img itemprop="image" src="…" />
  <div itemprop="name">
    <a href="…" itemprop="url">…</a>
  </div>
  <span itemprop="description">…</span>
</div>
```

That is fine from the Microdata and the Schema.org perspectives.